# How to revoke mint and freeze authority on mpl token with solana cli

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, solana-cli, metadata, mpl-token-metadata

I need a bit of help with a umi project I made. I created a token like this,

```
import { percentAmount, generateSigner, signerIdentity, createSignerFromKeypair } from "@Metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { TokenStandard, createAndMint } from "@Metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import { createUmi } from "@Metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import { mplCandyMachine } from "@Metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine";

import "@solana/web3.js";

import secret from './guideSecret.json';

const umi = createUmi('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'/);

const userWallet = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(secret));
const userWalletSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, userWallet);

const mint = generateSigner(umi);
umi.use(signerIdentity(userWalletSigner));
umi.use(mplCandyMachine());

createAndMint(umi, {
    mint,
    authority: umi.identity,
    name: metadata.name,
    symbol: metadata.symbol,
    uri: metadata.uri,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
    decimals: 6,
    amount: 420000000000_000,
    tokenOwner: userWallet.publicKey,
    tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi).then(() => {
    console.log("Succesfully minted 420 million tokens", mint.publicKey);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error minting tokens:", error);
});
```

I wanted to use the solana cli to revoke the mint and freeze authority but kept on getting these error messages,

```
PS C:\Users\Student\Documents\dabby_token> spl-token authorize DDjHRmoFg2FzWsnFD5Pyeif3keRHcozyyRjrmiPHoDX3 mint --disable
PS C:\Users\Student\Documents\dabby_token> solana-tokens authorize DDjHRmoFg2FzWsnFD5Pyeif3keRHcozyyRjrmiPHoDX3 mint --disable
error: Found argument 'authorize' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got it right, using `spl-token`. `solana-tokens` is not what you're looking for, and is more for large distributions of tokens. Here are the commands to run:

```
spl-token authorize DDjHRmoFg2FzWsnFD5Pyeif3keRHcozyyRjrmiPHoDX3 mint --disable
spl-token authorize DDjHRmoFg2FzWsnFD5Pyeif3keRHcozyyRjrmiPHoDX3 freeze --disable
```

Be sure to sign with the mint and freeze authorities, which you can specify with `--authority <KEYPAIR>`